# Facing errors in implementing jersey client for a simple RESTful CRUD webservice

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, crud, jersey-2.0

I am trying to make a CRUD RESTful Webservice using Jersey, but I am having trouble with the client. I tested my project by using Advanced Rest Client chrome app without the client and the functionality is fine but when I try to implement a client for it, I face 2 main issues, here are they:

1. When I am trying to implement "post" functionality or trying to implement "get" functionality (in get functionality I expect all the existing employees data to be printed). When the post request is processed, what is strange is that the employee data does get added but in console instead of response error is there. This is the error message :
   Nov 05, 2020 12:03:52 PM org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller deserializeItem
   SEVERE: Can't deserialize JSON array into: class com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response
   Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't deserialize JSON array into: class com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response
2. When I am trying to implement "put" functionality, what I am trying to do is send an employee object that JAXB can handle and add the employee data. The error that I face here is :
   Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.

Strangely enough the response of delete request is printed on console and no error is thrown.
Here are the various files of my project.

Employee.java

```
package com.wipro;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.json.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder= {"EmpId","EmpName","EmpDept","EmpAge"})
@JsonbPropertyOrder("{EmpId,EmpName,EmpDept,EmpAge}")
public class Employee {
private String EmpId;
private String EmpName;
private String EmpDept;
private int EmpAge;

public Employee() {
    
}
public Employee(String id,String name) {
    this.EmpId=id;
    this.EmpName=name;
}
public String getEmpId() {
    return EmpId;
}
public void setEmpId(String empId) {
    this.EmpId = empId;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return EmpName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.EmpName = empName;
}
public String getEmpDept() {
    return EmpDept;
}
public void setEmpDept(String empDept) {
    this.EmpDept = empDept;
}
public int getEmpAge() {
    return EmpAge;
}
public void setEmpAge(int empAge) {
    this.EmpAge = empAge;
}

}
```

EmployeeDao.java

```
package com.wipro;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public enum EmployeeDao {
object;

private Map<String, Employee> contentProvider = new HashMap<>();
private EmployeeDao() {
    Employee emp = new Employee("1","Mohit");
    emp.setEmpDept("I&ES");
    emp.setEmpAge(21);
    contentProvider.put("Mohit", emp);
    emp=new Employee("2", "Rohit");
    emp.setEmpDept("Digital");
    emp.setEmpAge(22);
    contentProvider.put("Rohit", emp);
}
public Map<String,Employee> getModel() {
    return contentProvider;
}
}
```

EmployeeResource.java

```
package com.wipro;

import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

@Path("/employee")
public class EmployeeResource {

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList(){
    List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    emp.addAll(EmployeeDao.object.getModel().values());
    return emp;
}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void putEmployee(JAXBElement<Employee> emp){
    Employee emps =emp.getValue();
    EmployeeDao.object.getModel().put(emps.getEmpId(), emps);
}

@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public void deleteEmployee(String name) {
    Employee emp = EmployeeDao.object.getModel().get(name);
    if(emp==null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Employee with name \""+name+"\" does not exist.");
    }
    EmployeeDao.object.getModel().remove(name);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{name}")
public void deleteEmployee1(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    Employee emp = EmployeeDao.object.getModel().get(name);
    if(emp==null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Employee with name \""+name+"\" does not exist.");
    }
    EmployeeDao.object.getModel().remove(name);
}

@POST
@Path("form")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void putEmployee(@FormParam("EmpId") String EmpId,@FormParam("EmpName") String 
EmpName,@FormParam("EmpDept") String EmpDept,@FormParam("EmpAge") int EmpAge) {
    Employee emp = new Employee(EmpId,EmpName);
    emp.setEmpDept(EmpDept);
    emp.setEmpAge(EmpAge);
    EmployeeDao.object.getModel().put(EmpName, emp);
}
}
```

EmployeeClient.java

```
package com.wipro;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.client.*;

public class EmployeeClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());
    
    String response = target.path("rest").path("employee").request().get(Response.class).toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    Employee emp = new Employee("3","Ankit");
    emp.setEmpDept("HR");
    emp.setEmpAge(21);
    target.path("rest").path("employee").request().put(Entity.entity(emp, 
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    System.out.println(response);
    response = target.path("rest").path("employee").request().get(Response.class).toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    response = target.path("rest").path("employee/Ankit").request().delete().toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("EmpId", "3");
    form.param("EmpName", "Ankit");
    form.param("EmpDept", "HR");
    form.param("EmpAge", "20");
    Response rest = target.path("rest").path("employee/form").request().post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED),Response.class);
    System.out.println(rest.getStatus());
}
private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/"+"Assignment_6").build();
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're using the wrong `Response`. Change the import.

Comment: That solved 2 of my problems, I am now getting correct response for get and post and delete method. Thanks

Comment: @PaulSamsotha while implementing put method from client I am getting error code 500 internal server error and it shows in console that jaxb implementation is missing, is it a problem of a missing jar or is there a problem while marshalling the java object?